# Flutter firebase streams

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am trying to use

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (context,snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                List<Text> messageWidgets=[];
                for(var message in messages){
                 final messageText=message.data['text'];
                 final messageSender=message.data['sender'];
                 final messageWidget=
                     Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                 messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
              }
            },
            ),

I am getting error in
final messageText=message.data['text'];
final messageSender=message.data['sender'];
```

I know it may be because of the new update but I want to access it and in documentation could not find anything like this.

In database in document I have two fields sender and text that is what I want to get individually out of data in messageText and messageSender. also please suggest some source where I could read so that next time I would not need to ask such question.

Comment: whats the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```dart
final messageText=message.data['text'];
final messageSender=message.data['sender'];
```

to:

```dart
final messageText=(message.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'];
final messageSender=(message.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['sender'];
```

The data contained in a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` can be retrieved by calling the `.data()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your time but that's not working. I used get('text) it worked fine.

Comment: That's alright. When you said "that's not working", what error did you get?

Comment: It just showed red line under ['text'] and failed to run

Comment: Can you hover your mouse on the red line and see what the actual error is? The red lines always have a corresponding error.

Comment: Yes sure, The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)  Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: Alright. I've updated my answer with a fix for that red line error. Kindly try it out and let me know if it works.